# Detect if code is C

Tags: python, c

I am currently using Python to write a compiler manager. I have to detect whether given source code is C, even if the code has a few syntax errors. I am currently using the file's extension to tell, but I want a smarter option.

Would using regex be the best (and simplest) solution to this problem?

I am also looking to minimize dependencies. I don't want to use a 3rd party package for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Write a simple C parser.  If it can tokenize a majority of your source text without errors, it's probably C.

Comment: C opposed to what other languages? C++? Objective C? Good luck.

Comment: @Doc Brown Just if it is C or not.

Comment: @NickPandolfi: you completely missed my point. For the two languages I mentioned, even a human cannot always tell.

Comment: What's the issue in not relying on the extension? Have you got trolls in your dev-environment?

Comment: @Thomas Kilian Im writing an autocompiler. I want it to detect source code in nonstand extensions.

Comment: Again: why? Trolls?

Comment: @Doc Brown So youre telling me theres no difference?

Comment: Am I speaking english?

Comment: You can write C++ code that's 100% C. So would you just send it to a C-Compiler instead? You should explain your issue.

Comment: @Thomas Kilian Correct, if it looks like C, it will be sent to a C compiler. Im only working with C. I just need to detect if a file contains C vs is a README file. With enough precision to be automatically reliable.

Comment: Using the extension will give you far more accurate results than trying to guess at it, is a well-accepted convention and takes almost to time to handle.  An empty file is a valid C translation unit when compilers not set to be pedantic; how would you differentiate that from an empty text file?

Comment: @Blrfl Good point!

Comment: And: what about a text file that just contains the content of a valid C-program? It's not intended to be compiled. You still have not elaborated on the reasons of your doing.

Comment: A regex is not anywhere *near* sufficient - you'd need something that can recognize C syntax.

Comment: The thing that's best at "recongnizing C syntax" is - The C compiler. Why not just use that to check?

Comment: Isn't what Nick is suggesting essentially very similar to what the automatic code block recognition engine does on Stack Overflow? It seems like a valid question to me even if making an auto-compiler like this is a bad idea.

Comment: I still dont know if people downvoted this question into oblivion because its not worded/asked correctly, or it is bad practice. Downvotes should require an explanation. If its not good to do this, an answer could be "just use the extension", right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex would be the simplest, but not necessarily the best. A regex might be fooled by C-code residing in a comment of another language. It also might miss perfectly valid C-code that doesn't follow the whitespace convention you expect.

A C parser, as suggested, is probably the best you can do. There are tools such as [ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/python-target.md) that can make this job easier for you (ANTLR can generate Python lexer/parsers for C and other languages). Once you've run the C-code through your parser, you can compare the number of syntax errors to the number of valid tokens and size of the C file. Based on these statistics, you can make a guess.

As others have noted--you still won't be able to tell the difference between a valid C++ file and a C file with some syntax errors (unless you also run your C-code through a C++ parser, and an Objective-C parser, and...).

If you're already making an auto-compiler, your best bet might be to compile the code in all your supported languages and pick the one that actually compiles. If the input file may actually have syntax errors, pick the language that compiles with the fewest syntax errors. You'll still run into the problem where a given input file compiles just fine in multiple languages (as mentioned, C and C++ is one example). You'll end up with multiple compilers that work just fine for the given input file--the only way you'll be able to tell which one to use is by... ...looking at the file extension.

Comment: I settled on just using the extension, but this answer would have been the best way to automatically determine what I wanted.